# IP address and Geolocation

Tags: javascript, php, networking, server-side

How accurate is IP based Geolocation?

Can it be used for server redirection based on IP address/location?
Any other method to get exact zipcode of that location?

Comment: Accuracy rates on naming the city from an IP address vary between 50%-80%. Determining the nation of an Internet user is 95%-99% percent accurate, for reasons that have to do with how IP addresses are allocated and registered. Above only counts if the user is not using a proxy.

Comment: You will not be able to get an accurate zip code but for country location IP is a valid option but  not 100%. you can consider also the HTML5 Geolocation

Comment: It may depend where in the world your users are from - if they are broadly from one country, it may be worth specifying that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How accurate is IP based Geolocation?

Country level (or in the US state level) is usable, beyond that it's not precise enough. I don't have specific statistics, but from experience I would guess a rate around 70% correct results for city level precision. And around 95+% correct results for countries.

> Can it be used for server redirection based on IP address/location?

Depends on how what you wish to redirect to. If you wish to redirect to city specific pages then it's probably not a wise plan. On the other hand if you wish to redirect to different language versions of your site you're better off looking at the language request headers.

> Any other method to get exact zipcode of that location?

The most precise results that are possible to get is using the HTML5 Geolocation, obviously that is however client side and not server side.

Comment: what is the wise plan for redirecting to city specific pages/servers?

Comment: @RohitJaiswal What about asking the user?